# Drush is failing to install: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: drush

I've got Composer installed globally according to the instructions given on https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally and then tried to install drush. Unfortunately, drush is failing to install giving the following error:

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/console v3.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.1].
    - symfony/console v3.0.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.16) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/console v3.0.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.16) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
    - psy/psysh v0.6.1 requires symfony/console ~2.3.10|^2.4.2|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.1].
    - Installation request for psy/psysh v0.6.1 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.6.1].
```

even though the http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install lists:

```
Drush 8 master  PHP 5.4.5+
```

My environment is:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

and unfortunately I can not upgrade PHP because I need to strictly follow RHEL/CentOS official versions.

Then I decided to give a try to Drush 7.x branch and unfortunately it is also giving:

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for symfony/console v3.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.1].
- symfony/console v3.0.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.16) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- symfony/console v3.0.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.16) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
- psy/psysh v0.6.1 requires symfony/console ~2.3.10|^2.4.2|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.1].
- Installation request for psy/psysh v0.6.1 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.6.1].
```

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it like this? Do this for the latest HEAD version:

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

Do this if you want a specific version, for example the latest release of version 7:

```
composer global require drush/drush:7.*
```

Comment: Yes, I did, however unfortunately it shows the above described dependency. I've manually symlinked path to drush command to be executable and it is working for me now, however the "official" way of installing still fails for me.